# is it possible to loop lines in notepad++?

Tags: regex

I have a txt file with patterned content:

```
Line 1 id=1234
Line 2 id=0001
Line 3 id=4321
Line 4 id=9281
Line 5 id=6631
Line 6 id=1234
Line 7 id=1234
Line 8 id=4321
Line 9 id=7772
Line 10 id=0001
... up to Line 5000 id=6631
```

I want to replace all repetitive contents (ie. Line 1, 6, 7) to only for the first occur. of content (Line 1 id=1234; 6, 7 removed). In other words, content id of a line must occur once. Is that possible though regular expressions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that a line would literally read `Line 1 id=1234`:

- Enter `(Line [0-9]+ id=)([0-9]+)(.*?)(Line [0-9]+ id=)\2\n` into the find box, and `\1\2\3` into the replace with box.
- Make sure that `Regular Expression` is selected and `. matches newline` is checked.
- Press `Replace All`, until all duplicates are removed.
- You will see `Replace All: 0 occurrence was replaced.` when it's complete.

Assuming instead that the lines would read only `id=1234`:

- Enter `(id=[0-9]+)(.*?)\1\n` into the find box, and `\1\2` into the replace with box.
- Make sure that `Regular Expression` is selected and `. matches newline` is checked.
- Press `Replace All`, until all duplicates are removed.
- You will see `Replace All: 0 occurrence was replaced.` when it's complete.